# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and NVIDIA 390

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have installed the NVIDIA 390.77 on an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop machine. I have a dedicated NVIDIA GPU, and I want to run Simulation Programs such as Gazbeo on it, using the GPU for rendering the visual output. It worked on a previous install with Ubuntu 16, where the nvidia-smi showed the prozess among the GPU processes. This is not the case on a new install with Ubuntu 18.

There seems also something wrong with running nvidia-settings (see last code sniplet). I dont really get whats wrong, as there are 2 processes running as gpu processes....

As far is I understand I dont need anyoffloading, as I have only one GPU.

What I hope to achieve:

1.) Let the simulation client (gzclient) use the GPU for rendering.
2.) Get nvidia-settings running.

Any help is very appriciated.

BR

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:65:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:92 memory:d7000000-d7ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:b000(size=128) memory:d8000000-d807ffff
```

The output from nvidia-smi looks good. There are even 2 GPU processes running:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P400         Off  | 00000000:65:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 34%   32C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    144MiB /  1991MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1143      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            69MiB |
|    0      1180      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          72MiB |
```

The output of dpkg -l looks like this. So the xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 is also installed.

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                         390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                  390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                      390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                       390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                        390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                      390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-cuda-dev                              9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                              9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                              9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Debugger (GDB)
ii  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                          9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                              390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                            390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-opencl-dev:amd64                      9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL development files
ii  nvidia-prime                                 0.8.8.2                                     all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-profiler                              9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  nvidia-settings                              390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                             390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-visual-profiler                       9.1.85-3ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA Visual Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390                390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

The output of dmesg looks like this:  the line  module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel looks supicious.

```
[    1.453703] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.453708] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.468050] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.472932] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[    1.473151] nvidia 0000:65:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    1.478049] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  390.77  Tue Jul 10 22:10:46 PDT 2018
[    1.478697] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00006500] Loading driver
[    1.478698] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:65:00.0 on minor 0
[   13.241642] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 237
```

nvidia-xconfig shows this output

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.


WARNING: Unable to parse X.Org version string.

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found

ERROR: Unable to write to directory '/etc/X11'.
```

nvidia-settings

```
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


(nvidia-settings:13915): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:55:23.291: Error loading theme icon 'dialog-question' for stock: Icon 'dialog-question' not present in theme Adwaita
** Message: 14:55:23.295: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 14:55:23.295: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application
       profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

Comment: Addition: This behaviour occurs, when logging in with remote desktop. On the host machine nvidia-settings works and also offloading to gpu. I can only choose Xorg sessions. Is this different to a nvidia-xorg session?

Comment: xorg file is missing. Try nvidia-xconfig  as per the document https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-8776/README/chapter-03.html